# How can a terminal be embedded in a PyQt window in OS X?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, pyqt, xterm

I've written a PyQt GUI that features an embedded terminal (`xterm`). I use Ubuntu and it works fine on that but I've found that some colleagues who run OS X are having difficulties: the terminal is showing up as a separate window. How should I get the terminal embedded in OS X? I need the GUI to look the same on both Linux and OS X.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class embedded_terminal(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        self.terminal = QWidget(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.terminal)
        self.process.start('xterm', ['-into', str(self.terminal.winId())])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = embedded_terminal()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the OSX package for xterm does have the `-into` option.

Comment: Read the tag descriptions! "embedded" is not "embedding".

Comment: @ThomasDickey Thanks for mentioning that. It doesn't seem to be working in the same way as it does for Linux.

Comment: @Olaf Thanks for pointing that out.